# Capture and log iOS timeouts

Tags: ios

iTunes Connect provides timeout reports alongside crash and memory reports. Is it possible to trap these timeouts so we can log them and send to our servers?

Answer (score 0):

No. An external system process is monitoring the apps and whenever it decides that such a problem occurs it kills the app. There is no way to run your own code when such a kill happens, and there is no way to get an information why the kill happens.

That system process is then generating arbitrary crash reports which are send to iTunes Connect.